# Create functions in R

Tags: r, algorithm, function

I'm fairly new to R and I have not been working with functions in R before.
I want to write a program/algorithm (using R) that calculates the square root of a given positive number.
Would anyone mind take the time to give me an example of how this can be achieved?

Thanks a lot in advance!

UPDATE

```
 posNum_to_squaRtNum <- function(posNum) {
if (posNum <= 0)
  print("Due to mathmatical principles you have to input a positive number")
else
  squaRtNum <- sqrt(posNum)
  return(squaRtNum)
```

}

When I insert a negative number in the function, the output is my print PLUS the error: "Error in posNum_to_squaRtNum(-1) : object 'squaRtNum' not found." It should not go on to the else statement, if the if statement is fulfilled right?

Comment: The most trivial solution: my_sqrt <- function(x) { retVal <- sqrt(x); return(retVal) }

Comment: Okay, that seems pretty straightforward. I was expecting something more technical. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please check out post update

Comment: If you want to actually write a function that calculates the square root, a web search will surface the algorithms.

Comment: "Due to mathmatical principles you have to input a positive number" -- the number `i` would beg to differ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your `if` conditions in brackets:

```
posNum_to_squaRtNum <- function(posNum) {
  if (posNum <= 0) {
    print("Due to mathmatical principles you have to input a positive number")
 } else {
    squaRtNum <- sqrt(posNum)
  return(squaRtNum)
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting the gist of it now.